# gradle where exactly to put "apply plugin"?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin

i'm trying to add Google analytics inside of the my app using this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

But i stucked on the problem, where to exactly put the line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So my build.gradle top level file is looking like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But this is wrong. Where to put apply plugin exactly please?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In andriod studio you have this kind of structure:

```
root
   build.gradle
   app
      build.gradle
```

In the top-level build.gradle you have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In your `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 //...


dependencies{
   //.....
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be inside of the object

```
allprojects
```

Answer (score 0):

on top of the app **build.grade**

like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```